# FIR filter design by the Fourier transform method

Tags: fourier-transform, filter-design, finite-impulse-response

I am having some problems understanding how the Fourier transform method is used to determine the FIR filter.

As far as i have understood, you start by using the ideal impulse reponse for the specific filter design you want to have.  Those are given in this table[image]

As the the ideal impulse reponse contains infinite impulses, we truncate the infinite to finite a number by $m$, (which is confusing how this is done).

But my question is how do predetermine the order of the filter, without having to try randomly, using this method?

Comment: there are multiple issues.  first you are using the rectangular window, which is the worst one.  second, if you are designing an FIR using a good window (like Kaiser), there are heuristic formulae that give you and idea of what M to use for a given width of the transition region and a given stopband attenuation.

Comment: how do you determine M.. ? how do you determine which window should be used?

Comment: user, i just now saw this on top of the list.  sorry about the month-long delay.  i have no idea where this table came from but, in my opinion, it's a little bit misleading.  the determination of how big M must be is, in this case, heuristic, although i imagine that some approximate formula might pop up.  for the Kaiser window, there are well-established formulae.

Comment: Check Julius Smith books: [Mathematics of the DFT with Audio applications](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mdft/) and [Introduction to digital filters](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/).

Comment: If I understand correctly M is the length of the impulse. How is the truncation done? Simply by setting every value outside the window 0 (this is so called rectangular window), or perhaps by using a other windowing function, thus altering values inside the window. This is equivalent to convolution by the frequency response of the windowing function in the frequency domain. The design aspects depends on the application. I can tell you that longer window always gives you more freedom with regards to the frequency and phase response (unless the data has a sample constraint). Windowing a specific

Comment: Your question has beeen answered. Do not hesitate to vote for the useful ones and accept the most suitable

Answer (score 2):

Some papers provide rule-of-thumb formula for the filter length (and coefficient quantization), for instance:

- [Accurate estimation of minimum filter length for optimum FIR digital filters](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/82.877143), 2000, Ichige *et al.*
- [On computational complexity in digital filters](http://dx.doi.org/10.1049/iet-cds.2010.0010), 1981, Bellanger
- [FIR Digital Filter Design Techniques Using Weighted Chebyshev Approximation](http://bme.elektro.dtu.dk/31610/documents/R_M_P_1975.pdf), 1975, Rabiner *et al.*

The one I generally  use in lectures is borrowed from the second paper, for a low-pass filter with the following design:

[image]

Then, the estimated filter length $N$ (apparently $2M+1$ for you) is, with sampling frequency $f_s$:

$$ N = \frac{2 f_s}{3(f_2-f_1)}\log_{10} \left(\frac{1}{10\delta_1\delta_2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

There are three main characteristics of the filters that are affected by the filter length

1. Passband Ripple
2. Transition Width (from passband to stop band, or stop band to passband)
3. Stopband attenuation and roll-off of sidelobes

Unfortunately, there aren't any formulas for how the length of the window and the type of window used affect all of these 3 aspects of the filter. So you may need to increase the filter length to meet your passband ripple requirement, but it may not meet your required attenuation and/or roll-off requirement, so you'll need an even longer filter. This will need to be done by trial and error.

I believe there were some articles in the IEEE that gave some length formulas when using the Kaiser window, but I don't have the references at hand.

Even the length formulas for using the Parks–McClellan design (Remez exchange) are just a heuristic and were developed after performing a lot of experiments. Even these formulas can fail, often when a corner frequency is near 0 Hz or Fs/2. Most of the time these formulas are a good first estimate you may need a few extra coefficients to meet your exact requirements. Using the estimate of the filter order for the PM algorithm is a good first estimate for the minimum length of your filter using a windowing filter design technique.

Comment: David, for the Kaiser window and stop-band attenuation of more than 50 dB, there **is** this heuristic: $$ L \ = \ \frac{A-8}{2.285 \ \Delta\omega} + 1$$  where  $A$ is the stopband attenuation in dB (and directly related to the passband ripple, they're not independent), $\Delta \omega$ is the transition width in normalized frequency, and $L$ is the FIR length in number of taps.

Answer (score 0):

The higher the filter order is, the steeper or less rippled (,,smoother''?) a filter approximating a certain prototype can be. So you would select the highest order feasible. Often the desired order may be specified. Common window functions will ,,smear out'' ripples (averaging them out) and make the filter less steep. Windowing and Filtering are acutally dual to each other, you could think of a window as a low pass filter for the frequency domain.

Comment: So there is no way to determine M, and thereby the order???

Comment: If other parameters are known, then maybe one could determine m. But generally, like that, almost every answer is likely to be vague. There are somewhat obvious rules of thumb, as in that you'd have to "catch" at least a significant fraction of the energy of the sinc. This is easier if the band edge is near the Nyquist frequency, and harder if it's close to 0. Often, however, parameters are so tight that you need to go further than just a sampled sinc.

Comment: Imagine you want to make an highpass filter with an cutoff freq at 8000 hz, fs = 20000 hz. 
Would you be able to make FIR filter out from these information, or do have to know how many taps it includes.. 
Those few rules of thump, what are those??

Comment: The more coefficients you use, the better your filter will "cut off". It's a trade-off. What attenuation are you trying to achieve?

Comment: More coeffiecient => Higher order => sharper roll off..
I am just trying to come up with an random example, when designing IIR filter you would usually use the attenuation to determine the order, but is the formula for IIR the same for FIR?? 
Let's say we want it to be - 50dB at the stopband..

Comment: With about 20000 coefficients you appear to come close to that value. The Remez algorithm gives a filter with 100 coefficients, with a stopband at 9300..10000 Hz. And, yes, if you want to suppress a signal more than a B or two, it gets quite hard.

Comment: But how did you come up with up 20000 coefficients.. I would like know how you with the atteneuation can calculate the amount of coefficient?

Comment: By trial and error, actually. It's just "rules of thumb" at best.

Comment: So...  you plotted the magnitude response from 0th - 40000th order and checkhed wheather it had wanted response => Stopband attenuation at - 50 dB..

Comment: Kinda like that, yes. Actually, I started with 100, and raised until I was satisfied.

Comment: I can't believe there isn't a way to analytically solve the answer..

Comment: It depends on the constraints. If there's enough data points, you can get a real answer. Cutoff frequency and characteristic is not enough.

Answer (score -3):

You design a filter with the desired frequency in mind that you whish to extract. So by designing such a filter you will elimnate undesired frequencies.